# ApplicationSettingsBase.Save: Unable to save config to file

Tags: winforms, configuration, citrix, file-access, xenapp

What could cause ApplicationSettingsBase.Save to fail with the error "Unable to save config to file "?

```
if (Settings.Default.CallUpgrade)
{
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.CallUpgrade = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

```
Exception Type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Exception Message: Konfiguration konnte nicht in Datei "C:\Users\u00001\AppData\Roaming\CompanyName\ApplicationName.ex_StrongName_4vozv12n21s5wt5tg4h44jakrs6m65xy\3.0.0.1\user.config" gespeichert werden.

Stack Trace:
   bei System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.ReplaceFile(String Source, String Target)
   bei System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
   bei System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   bei System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   bei System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ClientSettingsConfigurationHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   bei System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   bei System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   bei System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
```

In addition to user.config, the folder contains another file named a2rx2s4u.newcfg.
The user running the application has full control on the folder.

The application is run on a Windows 2019 Server with Citrix XenApp.

I've logged the activity of the app with Sysinternals Process Monitor. As far as I understand, the application tries to rename a2rx2s4u.newcfg to user.config replacing the existing user.config, and that seems to fail:

```
Operation: IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION
Result: 0xC0000369
Path: C:\Users\u00001\AppData\Roaming\CompanyName\ApplicationName.ex_StrongName_4vozv12n21s5wt5tg4h44jakrs6m65xy\3.0.0.1\a2rx2s4u.newcfg
Type: SetRenameInformationFile
ReplaceIfExists: True
FileName: C:\Users\u00001\AppData\Roaming\CompanyName\ApplicationName.ex_StrongName_4vozv12n21s5wt5tg4h44jakrs6m65xy\3.0.0.1\user.config
```

Stack trace from Process Explorer:

```
    "Frame","Module","Location","Address","Path"
"0","FLTMGR.SYS","FLTMGR.SYS + 0x555d","0xfffff8058039555d","C:\Windows\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS"
"1","FLTMGR.SYS","FLTMGR.SYS + 0x50bc","0xfffff805803950bc","C:\Windows\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS"
"2","FLTMGR.SYS","FLTMGR.SYS + 0x4c28","0xfffff80580394c28","C:\Windows\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS"
"3","FLTMGR.SYS","FLTMGR.SYS + 0x4a1e","0xfffff80580394a1e","C:\Windows\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS"
"4","ntoskrnl.exe","ntoskrnl.exe + 0x38109","0xfffff8016c0db109","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"
"5","ntoskrnl.exe","ntoskrnl.exe + 0x10b343","0xfffff8016c1ae343","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"
"6","ntoskrnl.exe","ntoskrnl.exe + 0x11a4ac","0xfffff8016c1bd4ac","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"
"7","ntoskrnl.exe","ntoskrnl.exe + 0x1c8605","0xfffff8016c26b605","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"
"8","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x9fc44","0x7ffb5408fc44","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
"9","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0x14a35","0x7ffb53ca4a35","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"10","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0xa507","0x7ffb53c9a507","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"11","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0x7783","0x7ffb53c97783","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"12","wow64cpu.dll","wow64cpu.dll + 0x1783","0x775f1783","C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll"
"13","wow64cpu.dll","wow64cpu.dll + 0x1199","0x775f1199","C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll"
"14","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0xcfda","0x7ffb53c9cfda","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"15","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0x17dfd","0x7ffb53ca7dfd","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"16","wow64win.dll","wow64win.dll + 0x2e0f","0x7ffb53ee2e0f","C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll"
"17","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0xa34b4","0x7ffb540934b4","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
"18","ntoskrnl.exe","ntoskrnl.exe + 0x672ae5","0xfffff8016c715ae5","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"
"19","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0x65ff7","0xfffff4df95065ff7","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"20","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0x65d20","0xfffff4df95065d20","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"21","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0x65796","0xfffff4df95065796","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"22","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0x652dc","0xfffff4df950652dc","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"23","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0xa033e","0xfffff4df950a033e","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"24","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0x5a972","0xfffff4df9505a972","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"25","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0x5a020","0xfffff4df9505a020","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"26","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0xec27c","0xfffff4df950ec27c","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"27","win32kfull.sys","win32kfull.sys + 0xce961","0xfffff4df950ce961","C:\Windows\System32\win32kfull.sys"
"28","ntoskrnl.exe","ntoskrnl.exe + 0x1c8605","0xfffff8016c26b605","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"
"29","wow64win.dll","wow64win.dll + 0xf5b4","0x7ffb53eef5b4","C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll"
"30","wow64win.dll","wow64win.dll + 0x36d2","0x7ffb53ee36d2","C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll"
"31","wow64win.dll","wow64win.dll + 0x19fe","0x7ffb53ee19fe","C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll"
"32","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0x7783","0x7ffb53c97783","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"33","wow64cpu.dll","wow64cpu.dll + 0x1783","0x775f1783","C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll"
"34","wow64cpu.dll","wow64cpu.dll + 0x1199","0x775f1199","C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll"
"35","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0xcfda","0x7ffb53c9cfda","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"36","wow64.dll","wow64.dll + 0xcea0","0x7ffb53c9cea0","C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll"
"37","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0xd5c7d","0x7ffb540c5c7d","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
"38","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0xc38b9","0x7ffb540b38b9","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
"39","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x756c3","0x7ffb540656c3","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
"40","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x7566e","0x7ffb5406566e","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
"41","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x7090c","0x7767090c","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll"
"42","KernelBase.dll","KernelBase.dll + 0x121517","0x76341517","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll"
"43","KernelBase.dll","KernelBase.dll + 0x121338","0x76341338","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll"
"44","Sfrhook.dll","Sfrhook.dll + 0x2ae7","0x730a2ae7","C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\Sfrhook.dll"
"45","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xa427d","0x6d92427d","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"46","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xc4c31","0x6d944c31","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"47","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xc4bbd","0x6d944bbd","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"48","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xc49c3","0x6d9449c3","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"49","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xc42c2","0x6d9442c2","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"50","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xc4334","0x6d944334","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"51","System.ni.dll","System.ni.dll + 0x75e36e","0x705ee36e","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\9d718786e2ea160f395d8ee3d2488791\System.ni.dll"
"52","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xc225c","0x6d94225c","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"53","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xb6d07","0x6d936d07","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"54","System.Configuration.ni.dll","System.Configuration.ni.dll + 0xab5cd","0x6d92b5cd","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\727d61c30dcf1fe944a3c6110c244de8\System.Configuration.ni.dll"
"55","System.ni.dll","System.ni.dll + 0x6423f0","0x704d23f0","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\9d718786e2ea160f395d8ee3d2488791\System.ni.dll"
"56","System.ni.dll","System.ni.dll + 0x643fcf","0x704d3fcf","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\9d718786e2ea160f395d8ee3d2488791\System.ni.dll"
"57","<unknown>","0xccf4cde","0xccf4cde",""
"58","System.ni.dll","System.ni.dll + 0x646425","0x704d6425","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\9d718786e2ea160f395d8ee3d2488791\System.ni.dll"
"59","System.ni.dll","System.ni.dll + 0x64624f","0x704d624f","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\9d718786e2ea160f395d8ee3d2488791\System.ni.dll"
"60","System.ni.dll","System.ni.dll + 0x641636","0x704d1636","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\9d718786e2ea160f395d8ee3d2488791\System.ni.dll"
"61","<unknown>","0x9e7637a","0x9e7637a",""
"62","<unknown>","0x9e75ff5","0x9e75ff5",""
"63","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x8b8b0c","0x60988b0c","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"64","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x8bcc03","0x6098cc03","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"65","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0xc43fe4","0x60d13fe4","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"66","<unknown>","0xa4b0385","0xa4b0385",""
"67","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c2ff3","0x60292ff3","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"68","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c2f85","0x60292f85","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"69","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c28c0","0x602928c0","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"70","<unknown>","0x32dd446","0x32dd446",""
"71","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x45cab","0x77495cab","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"72","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x367bc","0x774867bc","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"73","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x3635a","0x7748635a","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"74","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x4312f","0x7749312f","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"75","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x72aed","0x77672aed","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll"
"76","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x37b5f","0x77487b5f","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"77","uxtheme.dll","uxtheme.dll + 0x32dca","0x74342dca","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll"
"78","uxtheme.dll","uxtheme.dll + 0x32418","0x74342418","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll"
"79","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x37dd3","0x77487dd3","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"80","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x45cab","0x77495cab","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"81","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x367bc","0x774867bc","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"82","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x35d0f","0x77485d0f","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"83","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c35d7","0x602935d7","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"84","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1cca34","0x6029ca34","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"85","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0xc4180c","0x60d1180c","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"86","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1cc9c1","0x6029c9c1","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"87","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1cdae3","0x6029dae3","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"88","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x8bd542","0x6098d542","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"89","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0xc43ea9","0x60d13ea9","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"90","<unknown>","0xa4b0385","0xa4b0385",""
"91","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c2ff3","0x60292ff3","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"92","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c2f85","0x60292f85","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"93","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1c28c0","0x602928c0","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"94","<unknown>","0x32dd446","0x32dd446",""
"95","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x45cab","0x77495cab","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"96","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x367bc","0x774867bc","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"97","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x358fb","0x774858fb","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"98","user32.dll","user32.dll + 0x356d0","0x774856d0","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
"99","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x225f1d","0x602f5f1d","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"100","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1d34e3","0x602a34e3","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"101","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1d30d1","0x602a30d1","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"102","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x1d2f23","0x602a2f23","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"103","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x893c13","0x60963c13","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"104","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x8bbf5d","0x6098bf5d","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"105","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll","System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll + 0x8bbc0d","0x6098bc0d","C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\bf4d479ac30cbf95afe4c0d4de1fc37b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll"
"106","<unknown>","0x9f6225b","0x9f6225b",""
"107","<unknown>","0x9d89434","0x9d89434",""
"108","<unknown>","0x822b0f7","0x822b0f7",""
"109","<unknown>","0x3411f66","0x3411f66",""
"110","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0xf036","0x7200f036","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"111","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x122da","0x720122da","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"112","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1859b","0x7201859b","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"113","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1bb11b","0x721bb11b","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"114","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1bb7fa","0x721bb7fa","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"115","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1bb727","0x721bb727","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"116","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1bb8a8","0x721bb8a8","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"117","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1bb9ce","0x721bb9ce","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"118","clr.dll","clr.dll + 0x1b7305","0x721b7305","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"
"119","mscoreei.dll","mscoreei.dll + 0xfa84","0x7294fa84","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll"
"120","mscoree.dll","mscoree.dll + 0xe80e","0x74bee80e","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll"
"121","mscoree.dll","mscoree.dll + 0x143f8","0x74bf43f8","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll"
"122","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x666ed","0x776666ed","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll"
"123","ntdll.dll","ntdll.dll + 0x666bd","0x776666bd","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll"
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a 32-bit Windows at hand, and as the application is x86, Process Explorer cannot resolve symbols.

It might be interesting that the stack trace contains "Sfrhook.dll" which is the "Citrix Special Folder Hook DLL". I think this DLL implements Special Folder Redirection in Citrix.

According to the Windows Error Codes reference, the error code 0xC0000369 means STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_OBJECT_PARAMETER:

> The device object parameter is either not a valid device object or is not attached to the volume that is specified by the file name.

I do not understand this - the source and the target of the rename is in the same directory.

How to further narrow down this problem?

[EDIT1]
The user profile seems to reside in an FSLogix profile container:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fslogix/configure-profile-container-tutorial

> When using Profile Container, both applications and users see the profile as if it's located on the local drive.

[EDIT2]
We now have another customer which experiences the same problem.
This time: No Citrix, but "Windows 10 Enterprise multi-session" - also uses FSLogix Profile Containers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/windows-10-multisession-faq

Comment: Hi Exaiwitmx, we are having a similar issue, Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No. As a workaround, we now use a network drive instead - so the config file is not located in an FSLogix profile container any more, and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Note that you have to set adequate permissions on both the network share and the folder which contains the config file. Otherwise, you might run into this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/20946627/13039722

"Prepare the roaming user profile location
[...]
Change the share permission to allow the Authenticated Users group the Full Control permission."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766489(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Many thanks for the response, we had our own suspicions that it was related to FSLogix.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem as described in this issue. How exactly did you solve the problem with the network drive? The path of the user.config file can't be determined by yourself! How did you set the path for the user.config file to the network drive?

Comment: @StefanVettiger We've created a custom settings provider. I haven't written it myself and unfortunately, I cannot ask the person who has any more, but I think it might be based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398536/13039722

Answer (score 0):

We have found that in server 2019 it required the UAC virtualization setting needed to be disabled for user level writes.  Using Process Monitor, we found that when the error occurred, it wrote to a UAC event log. For legacy applications this issue occurs when the user.config file is being copied from the "user.newcfg" file that is just a temporary file the the .NET code creates.